# Programmatically create Entity with ReferenceProperty from Message in GAE datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I'd like to be able to automatically insert an entity with a reference t another entity directly from a message, using Google Endpoints.

To transmit `ReferenceProperty` in message, I use the encoded string value of the `Key`. That is fine for sending message, but when receiving message, and creating an entity of it, I cannot just pass the encoded string as a parameter to the constructor.

For instance, say I have two classes that inherits from `BaseModel` which itself inherits from `db.models`

```
class TestModel2(models.BaseModel):
    test_string = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class TestModel(models.BaseModel):
    test2 = db.ReferenceProperty(TestModel2)
    test2_id = property(models.BaseModel._get_attr_id_builder('test2'),
                       models.BaseModel._set_attr_id_builder('test2'))
```

And a message class

```
class TestModelMessage(messages.Message):
    test2_id = messages.StringField(4)
```

I want to be able to create an `Entity` `TestModel` directly of the `TestModelMessage`.

I managed to do it in the other way (from to entity to message) using a property. But in the other way it doesn't work since I have the feeling that the constructor for `db.models` will only set the attributes that inherits `db.Property`. Thus the setter for the property won't be called...

How could I do this?

I thought of overriding the `__init__` in `BaseModel` but then when calling the `__init__` of `db.models` it will probably override the `ReferenceProperty`.

Comment: From you description I can't actually work out what you are trying to do.  How about describing what you hope to achieve in terms of relationships between entities rather than describing code.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope I made it clearer.

Comment: Actually I am having trouble understanding this "I want to be able to create an Entity TestModel directly of the TestModelMessage."  Do you mean a reference, or should you use an ancestor relationship.  Also what are you trying to achieve with test2_id ?  Too much code and not enough elaboration. ALso you refer to not being able to pass encoded keys to constructors, but essentially you can, with only one extra step however you are not showing how you are trying to do that.  Overall your not clearly defining a question - you have a about 3 questions and a bunch of possibly invalid statements.

Comment: The problem is: how transmit entities that have references to other entities. Two solution I guess: Either you add a MessageField to your message and thus the message contains both full entities. Or you transmit a Key equivalent, in my case the encoded string key. I took the second option. Now it is easy to get the message's fields and pass them to the entity constructor, except for the encoded string key. Concerning the test2_id, it is a convenient property that allows me to access directly the encoded string key (when creating message from entity)

Comment: to get the string key use get_value_for_datastore on the reference property.  As in `TestModel.test2.get_value_for_datastore(self)` which will give you the key, and `str(key)` will give you an encoded key. That way you don't have tight bindings to the class etc..

Answer (score 0):

So, I added a `_ref_properties` field to the `BaseModel` class.
For the previous example, it would be `_ref_properties = {'test2': 'test2_id'}`

Then I added this class method

```
@classmethod
def from_message(cls, message, *args):
    attributes = {attr: getattr(message, attr) for attr in args}
    for attribute, property in cls._ref_properties.items():
        attributes[attribute] = db.Key(encoded=getattr(message, property))
    entity = cls(**attributes)
    return entity
```

And it seems to work. Probably not the best. Any remarks or better solution?